# Building a common communication interface

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, factory-pattern, abstraction

I'm having trouble building an abstract interface for multiple communication types that have different settings to connect. I would like to be able to use a factory of some sort to instantiate one of the communication types (usb, serial, tcp) with their appropriate connection arguments without branching this off into a bunch of if statements everywhere to check the type and to use a single interface to control all the interaction with the specified communication type.

Some code below to help illustrate my problem:

```
public interface ITransport : IDisposable
{
    event EventHandler Connected;
    event EventHandler Disconnected;
    event EventHandler<byte[]> SentData;
    event EventHandler<byte[]> ReceivedData;
    event EventHandler<string> ErrorOccurred;

    event HostCertificateReceivedDelegate HostValidation;

    Task<bool> ConnectAsync(TransportConnectionArgs connectionArgs);
    Task<bool> SendAsync(byte[] buffer);

    void Disconnect();
}

public class TransportConnectionArgs
{
    public static readonly TransportConnectionArgs Empty = new TransportConnectionArgs();
    protected TransportConnectionArgs() { }
}

public class SshTransportConnectionArgs : TransportConnectionArgs
{
    public string Host { get; }
    public int Port { get; }

    public string Username { get; }
    public string Password { get; }

    public SshTransportConnectionArgs(string host, int port, string username = "root", string password = "")
    {
        Host = host;
        Port = port;
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }
}

public class SerialTransportConnectionArgs : TransportConnectionArgs
{
    ... does not need password but needs com port, baud, etc...
}

public class UsbTransportConnectionArgs : TransportConnectionArgs
{
    ... does not need address or port or serial connection settings
}

public sealed class SshDebugClient : ITransport
{
    public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(SshTransportConnectionArgs connectionArgs)
    {
        ... access properties specific to a regular TCP connection
    }
}

public sealed class SerialDebugClient : ITransport
{
    public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(SerialTransportConnectionArgs connectionArgs)
    {
        ... access properties specific to a regular serial/COM connection
    }
}

public sealed class UsbDebugClient : ITransport
{
    public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(UsbTransportConnectionArgs connectionArgs)
    {
        ... access properties specific to a regular USB connection
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50454591/edit) and add a example of what a potential factory class would look like?

Comment: Without branching, how do you expect to differentiate your `TransportConnectionArgs`?  I feel like you are trying to optimize and improve your code without having built a working version of it yet.  In my experience, why would you not use a few `if` statements?  They are easy and do exactly what you want.

Comment: I'd consider a dependency injection container - Windsor, Autofac, etc. That way the class that needs an `ITransport` isn't responsible for instantiating it. The container does that. The concrete type that the container creates can have its own unique dependencies and the container will provide those as well, all unknown to the class that depends on `ITransport`.

Comment: @Sean I had a working version doing exactly what I wanted to avoid doing as suggested in the first post. I started modifying it and discovered that I'm not entirely sure how to abstract the logic. The communication functionality is consistent, but the arguments passed in to aid in the connection process aren't.

Comment: @ScottHannen Hmm that is some food for thought! Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, okay, depending on what you're looking for, this is either pretty easy or incredibly difficult.

Are you looking for a factory for the *args* class?  If so, you're going to have a rough time - since they all have different properties that you have to populate.  You don't want a global factory constructor that takes in every single possible field name and decides which type to use based on which values were populated.

But... if you're just looking for a constructor for the ITransport?  Then you can simply do:

```
public class Factory
{
    public static ITransport CreateTransport(TransportConnectionArgs args)
    {
        if (args is SshTransportConnectionArgs)
            return new SshDebugClient((SshTransportConnectionArgs)args);
        if (args is SerialTransportConnectionArgs)
            return new SerialDebugClient((SerialTransportConnectionArgs)args);
        // etc
    }
}
```

... or, if you're *really* opposed to those if lines?

Use reflection to find all non-abstract classes that implement ITransport, add an additional method to the ITransport, requiring implementers to return the type of args they work with, and then do something like:

```
public static ITransport CreateTransport(TransportConnectionArgs args)
{
    List<ITransport> allTranports = GetAllImplementersOf<ITransport>();
    foreach(ITransport transport in allTransports)
    {
        if (transport.NeededArgType == typeof(args))
            return transport;
    }
}
```

... Ultimately, though, I think one problem is that there's no 'hook' between your two classes.  You've got a transport type, and you've got an argument type... but you don't have any linking between them.  Part of me wonders if you should have the args be something that the Transport can create/parse, instead of having a separate independent class for it.

Comment: Actually, you raise a valid point. I don't really need a factory for the connection args because those come from various user controls fed back based on a radio button selection to determine the transport type. If I had a factory for that then it would probably have to consider the broad spectrum which seems pretty ugly. If I expand to multiple TCP transport types then internally that would make a bit more sense. Branching that out to serial or usb however, does not make as much sense.

Thankyou guys!

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick and, probably, not so clean idea.

If you move `TransportConnectionArgs` dependency from your `ITransport` interface to concrete implementations constructors, you will be able to implement rather generic instantiation method.

```
ITransport Create(TransportConnectionArgs connectionOptions)
{
    if (connectionOptions is SshTransportConnectionArgs sshOptions) 
    {
        return new SshDebugClient(sshOptions);
    } 
    else if (...)
    ...
    else 
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown connection type.");
    }
}

var transport = Create(new SshTransportConnectionArgs { ... });
var connected = await transport.ConnectAsync();
```

Nevertheless this won't work for sure if a single `ITransport` instance is expected to be reused with multiple `TransportConnectionArgs` instances, i.e expected to have multiple invocations of `ConnectAsync` with different options.

Comment: I'm only expecting one open connection at a time. I'll play around with this. I'm just reading this thread now so I've got some reading and testing to do with all these replies! :)